# Disagreement on closure of "Diffee-Hellmen in Javscript"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

The question [Diffee-Hellmen in Javscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113860/diffee-hellmen-in-javscript) was closed today for being unclear what the OP was asking for.

I disagree with this, however. The very beginning of the post says this:

> I need to do the equation:
>
> `(3x)mod17`
>
> This is an example so far. This is not for actual security,
>   but it lags out.

Right there - in the very beginning of the question - it explains what the post is about

- It needs to do that equation. It's name is given in the title. This is what the OP's code is doing.
- It "lags out" - it is slow. This is what the OP would like help with.

That being said, I don't see what is unclear about the post.

---

In the comment section of the post, I had a disagreement with a user about a link to a video that the OP put on their post. The video is about this `Diffee-Hellmen` problem/algorithm that the OP is trying to solve.

In my eyes, this video was put there as a reference for users who wanted to know more about this algorithm (hence the tag "Confused?" with the link).

However, the other user in the comment section said it made the post no longer "self contained" and this user may also have been using this as a reason for closure.

---

Note that I'm not saying that this post is necessarily a *good* post, I'm just saying that it is good enough and should not be marked off-topic.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with your assessment that while it's not a good question, it's still on topic.

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: Why was this closed in the first place?

Comment: I feel sorry for Whitfield Diffie and Martin Hellman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reopened the question.

It's not the greatest problem statement, but the code is working and it's up for review, and there's even a decent answer for it.

If OP (or someone) could summarize the video into a shorter and clearer explanation of the problem being solved, it might even get my upvote.